# height of element not updated after angularjs updates dom until I interact with page

Tags: angularjs

I'm just learning angularjs so apologies if I don't explain this well.

I have an unordered list populated from an array using an `ng-repeat`. The list contents can be changed by selecting a different category from a select box. When the list is scrolled down, it is further populated using an infinite-scroll type arrangement.

The problem is, after the array is changed by selecting a different category, the result of `elem.height()` (where `elem` refers to my `<ul>`) still reflects the height of the `<ul>` before it was updated. When I scroll the page down, the result of `elem.height()` is then updated to the correct value, but not before my infinite-scroll code has seen the old incorrect value and made an undesired http request.

I'm hoping this is enough information to describe my problem. Is there a way of forcing elem.height() to be updated after angularjs has modified the DOM?

Comment: can you make an example using  Plunker or jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm too tired to contemplate doing that tonight. I'll have a go tomorrow.